# How to import IntelliJ classes while developing IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: intellij-plugin

### TL;DR

How do I import the `com.intellij.psi.JavaPsiFacade` class in my IntelliJ plugin?

### Background Information

I'm trying to develop an IntelliJ plugin. I've been following the getting started guide [here](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html) and have been using Gradle with a Groovy build script.

I got the "Hello World" example to run. My next step was to try to use the Java PSI. My project will successfully build when I use some classes (e.g. `com.intellij.psi.DelegatePsiTarget`), but not others (e.g. `com.intellij.psi.JavaPsiFacade`).

I'm under the impression that to use certain classes I need to add their sources to my `build.gradle` class. However, I haven't had much luck figuring out how to track down which source would provide it and how to add the source once I find that out.

The idea I've had so far that seems closest is that I need to add a `plugins` section (as specified [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin#configuration)). However, my previous question still stands: how do I figure out what package provides what I want?

Here is my `build.gradle` file so far:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.4.13'
}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'

version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version '2019.2.4'
}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was writing this question, I finally ended up discovering my issue.

Since I was using a *Java* API, I needed to declare my dependency on the *Java* plugin, which was done in two parts:

1. Adding `plugins = ['java']` to my `intellij` object in `build.gradle` file.
2. Adding `<depends>com.intellij.modules.java</depends>` to my `plugin.xml` file.

Hopefully this helps someone else avoid the long road I took. If other people have more input, feel free to add additional answers.